# Recreate a bind to a unix socket with bound file removed

Tags: linux, mysql, socket

I've been confronted with a specific situation recently, searching through the internet and linux specs did not give a definitive answer. Well, I believe it's not possible but maybe you know the way.

The scenario is as follows

1. /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock created by a mysql process on start
2. /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock disappears e.g. removed by some external action
3. `ss -lpn | grep mysqld` still shows this unix socket

   `u_str  LISTEN     0      128    /var/lib/mysql/mysqld.sock -786114905            * 0                   users:(("mysqld",pid=30220,fd=41))`
4. `lsof -p 30220 | grep /var/lib/mysql/mysqld.sock` shows a process is bound to it

   `mysqld  30220 mysql   41u  unix 0xffff8800245603c0          0t0 3508852391 /var/lib/mysql/mysqld.sock`

Is it possible to recreate/restore the deleted unix socket file without the parent process restart so that clients can still connect through the this socket file as before the deletion?

Thanks.

Comment: unix/linux kernel use inode number, if you create one more time, you will get a new inode number, better if you restart the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the old Unix trick to recover a still open, but deleted file. In that case, you did most of the job there:

```
ss -lpn | grep mysqld 

u_str  LISTEN     0      128    /var/lib/mysql/mysqld.sock -786114905            * 0                   users:(("mysqld",pid=30220,fd=41))
```

Check the open files from the PID, here, 30220:

```
# ls -l /proc/30220/fd

lr-x------ 1 mysql mysql 64 janv. 15 19:04 0 -> /dev/null
l-wx------ 1 mysql mysql 64 janv. 15 19:04 1 -> /var/log/mysqld.log
lrwxrwxr-- 1 mysql mysql 64 janv. 15 19:04 2 -> /var/lib/mysql/mysqld.sock (deleted)
```

Now you can symlink `/proc/30220/fd/2` back to an alternate name (you won't be able to restore it to the same name however).

Comment: On Linux, you can create the symlink to have the same name as the original file had (i.e. `mysqld.sock`).